# Finding probability given COV and a specific probability value for a normal distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Given S is a random variable that follows normal distribution, **coefficient of variation of S being 20 %** and **P(S<=2) = 0.95**, how to  find the P(S>=2.5) ? Also, had this distribution been lognormal, instead of normal, how would the probability change in this case?

Comment: I'd just do it numerically.  I got $\mu\sim 1.50491$ pretty quickly.

Comment: Many authors insist that CV be used only for random variables $X$ with $P(X \ge 0) = 1.$ So, strictly speaking, CV could not apply to a normal RV, but might be OK if $\mu$ is several SDs above 0.

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sigma = 0.2\mu$, and so $S$ ~ $N(\mu, 0.2\mu)$. We also know $cdf(2) =0.95$, so plug this value in to the formula for CDF of a normal distribution, we have:
$$\frac{1}{2}(1 + erf(\frac{2-\mu}{0.2\mu\sqrt{2}})) = 0.95.$$
Solving for $\mu$, we'll have the distribution. We can then calculate $1-cdf(2.5)$. Lognormal is going to be similar, just a different CDF.